# Etymologie des kölschen "Mer" (1. Person Plural)

Tags: etymology, dialect, pronoun

Das Pronomen der ersten 1. Person Plural in der kölschen Mundart lautet "Mer", und in einigen angrenzenden Dialekten "Mir".

Diese Pronomen können gedeutet werden als Variation des deutschen "wir". Andererseits sind Wortwurzeln beginnend mit "m-" für Personalpronomen der ersten Person in den indogermanischen Sprachen nicht selten – siehe etwa Deutsch und Latein, dort allerdings nur im Singular. Hingegen kennen die slawischen Sprachen auch "Mi" als 1. Person Plural.

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Proto-Slavic/my

**Frage:** Was ist die Etymologie des kölschen "Mer"? Besteht hier eine etymologische Verwandtschaft mit slawischen Sprachen?

Comment: Auch in vielen österreichischen Dialekten sind Pronomen mit "m-" für die 1. Person Plural gebräuchlich.

Comment: Ich bin nicht sicher ob das ein Regionalismus ist, der sich auf Köln und Umgebung beschränkt.

Comment: Im Hessischen gibt es das auch. Zumindest hinter "haben" (wo es oft vorkommt) kann man es einfacher durch Maulfaulheit und Angleichung erklären: haben wir -> ham' mer

Comment: @dirkt: Bei "haben wir" ist "Maulfaulheit" (sprich Assimilation) denkbar, weil das "-en" von "haben" sich an das "b" bzgl. des Artikulationsortes angleicht (haben>habm, legen>legŋ). Bei Kontraktionen wie "simmer" für "sind wir", funktioniert diese Argumentation aber leider nicht mehr.

Comment: @Chris: "Sind" funktioniert ganz genauso, siehe "Sempf". :-) Das n ist einfach zu weit vorne, und für Dentale muss man die Zunge auch noch an die Zähne bringen, dann doch lieber gleich m, da muss man nicht viel tun...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In der [englischen Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_verbs#Colloquial_contractions_between_verb_and_personal_pronoun) wird behauptet, dass das Plural-Pronomen "mir" auf mittelhochdeutsche Zusammenziehungen wie "loufemir" aus "loufem wir" (laufen wir) zurückzuführen ist, wie sie heute noch in "hammer", "simmer" statt "haben wir" und "sind wir" auftreten. Laut der englischen Wikipedia war die entsprechende mittelhochdeutsche Verbendung nicht **-en**, sondern **-em**.

Anhand von der mir zur Verfügung stehenden Literatur (Bergmann: Alt- und Mittelhochdeutsch) finde ich aber nur die althochdeutsche Endung **-emēs** und die mittelhochdeutsche Endung **-en**. Eine Zwischenstufe **-em** ist meiner Meinung aber denkbar. (Wobei man nicht zwangsweise eine m-haltige Endung braucht. Es würde auch reichen, wenn "-en" und "w-" aufeinanderträfen und eine Assimilation derart stattfände, dass die Artikulationsart (nasal) von "n" und der Artikulationsort (labial) von "w" sich zu einem "m" kombinieren.)

Dass "mir" statt "wir" auch an anderen Positionen als hinter einem deklinierten Verb steht, wäre dann auf einen Analogieschluss zurückzuführen.

Comment: Nicht zu vergessen: Resi Berghammers "Oiso, gemma!"

Comment: Übrigens ist wohl ähnlich das "n" im schwedischen Pronomen "ni" (2. Person Plural) zu erklären. Fiel mir nur gerade ein ;)

Comment: Da wäre ich vorsichtig. Beispielsweise haben auch viele romanische Sprachen ein "n" als Anlaut in der 2. Pl. Das nur so am Rande ;)

Comment: @PatricHartmann, die romanischen Sprachen haben das *n* doch eher in der 1. Person Plural. Das schwedische *vi/ni* ist gerade anders herum als z. B. französisch *nous/vous*, was in dem zweiwöchigen Schwedischkurs, den ich mal besucht habe (und der mich selbstverständlich zum Experten gemacht hat), auch einige verwirrt hat. Dabei hätten wir das *vi* alleine wohl problemlos mit *wir* in Verbindung gebracht, und *i* wäre auch nicht so weit weg von *ihr*, doch da hat sich halt ein *n* eingeschlichen.

Comment: Der Einfluss der althochdeutschen Endung auf _-m_ ist äusserst unwahrscheinlich, zumal die ersten Belege für _mir/mer_ laut Idiotikon erst im 13. Jahrhundert auftreten.

Answer (score 5):

Swiss-German also uses "mer" instead of "wir".

"[Das Schweizerische Idiotikon](http://digital.idiotikon.ch/idtkn/id16.htm#page/161063/mode/1up)" (a dictionary of Swiss-German words with explanations on linguistics) had a short paragraph on this. According to that the *"mer/mir/mör"* is actually an assimilation where the *w* changed to *m* after words ending on *-en*.

Comment: The "Idiotikon" only mentions "mer". Just to clarify for the case that somebody checks the sources and can't find the other references. They haven't been added by me.

Comment: The Idiotikon mentions all these forms and numerous others. The forms are at the beginning of the article [wir](https://digital.idiotikon.ch/p/lem/241988), not at the end where the etymology is explained.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This might have changed then since the summer of 2014, good to know!

Answer (score 0):

Im Norwegischen gibt es zwei gängige Formen der 1. Person Plural (als Subjekt): "vi" (in Bokmål, Nynorsk und den meisten Dialekten) und "me" (vor allem in Nynorsk und südwestnorwegischen Dialekten).

Comment: Vielleicht noch etwas ausführen, wie das zusammenhängen könnte. Sonst wäre es vielleicht eher als Kommentar geeignet (obwohl, ja, du bist neu und kannst noch keine Kommentare schreiben, aber das wird schon :) )

Comment: Ja, mein Beitrag ist durchaus als Kommentar zu verstehen. Ich wollte nur darauf hinweisen (oder bestätigen), dass die pronominalen m-Formen der 1. Person Plural in germanischen Sprachen (und Dialekten) eine recht weite Verbreitung haben.

Answer (score 0):

Das "mer" für "wir" ist eine einfache Assimilation von w zu m (fast an der gleichen Artikulationsstelle), die nach bestimmten Konsonanten eintritt. Wurde oben bereits erwähnt. Typisches Beispiel:

"haben wir" wird in der lässigen Umgangssprache zu "ham" und "ham+wir" wird zu
"hammer".

Da steckt also keine andere Etymologie dahinter, es ist das gleiche Wort, das durch Assimilation verändert wurde. Also eine Sprechvereinfachung, wie sie vielfach und überall (in allen Sprachen) vorkommt.

Assimilation ist Konsonantenangleichung.

Das "mer" ist nicht nur Kölsch. Ich verwende es auch, obwohl ich in Bayern lebe. Ich bin zwar kein Bayer und spreche nicht bairisch, eher süddeutsches Hochdeutsch, mit Kölsch hab ich aber nichts zu tun. Und ich versteh die Burschen von da oben auch schlecht.